# Why Does UITextField Frame Change When Toggling Secure Text Entry?

Tags: uikit, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` that contains a trailing-edge button to toggle the text field's `isSecureEntry` value. The logic for toggling `isSecureEntry` works as expected, but the frame of the text field expands or contracts in height by a ~2.5 points when toggling `isSecureEntry`.

[image]

The two image assets used for the button measure 72x72 points, so I don't think the change is a result of changing the button's image.

We are using a custom font, so I thought that I may need to reset the font after each toggle of `isSecureEntry` (the text field's caret's height is also affected). The steps that I took follow:

1. I have subscribed to `UITextField.textDidChangeNotification`s in order to set the font after `isSecureEntry` is toggled, assuming that the change of characters would cause the notification to be posted, but that doesn't seem to happen because the breakpoint placed at the selector is not triggered.
2. I used the same logic to set the text field's font in the button's selector for the `touchUpInside` event, but that does't resolve the frame change either.

What may be causing the frame change of the text field when `isSecureEntry` is toggled?

Comment: If you change the custom font to a very large size, does the secure ... text frame and dots increase in size? Maybe iOS is not using your custom font in its scaling for the secure dots?

Comment: "I don't think the change is a result of changing the button's image." Have you tested this hypothesis? Maybe try removing the image variable from the equation?

Comment: @JoshBrown I modified the logic to keep the button's image the same in all states, and the resizing issue still occurs.

Comment: @stevekohls Unfortunately, the resizing issue still occurs when I use a custom font of any size. Also, it occurs when using iOS' system `.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)`.